# Add dynamic search to paginated WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, search

I am currently displaying a list of pages with "words" (English learning site) using WP_Query.
I want to add a search field at the top of the list, but in a way that would dynamically (is it AJAX?) modify the list below to display only the records that match with search field.

Test page: https://pweyigm9.ayz.pl/baza-wiedzy/slownictwo-angielskie/czasowniki/czasowniki-nieregularne/

Visualisation (hide red crossed records, because in "search field" there's a value to be looked for): [image: visualisation]

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'category_name' => $postcat[0]->slug,
        'posts_per_page' => 20,
        'orderby' => 'meta_value title',
        'meta_key' => 'poziom',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'paged' => $paged,
    );
    $arr_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $arr_posts->have_posts() ) :
        echo '<table class="vocab table table-bordered table-hover table-striped"><tbody><tr><th class="example">Infinitive</th><th class="example">Past simple</th><th class="example">Past participle</th><th class="example">polski</th></tr>';
        while ( $arr_posts->have_posts() ) :
            $arr_posts->the_post();
            ?>
                    <?php   
                echo '<tr><td>';
                echo do_shortcode(get_field('player1')); 
                echo '<a href="'.get_permalink($item->ID).'" title="'.$postcat[0]->name.': to '.get_the_title($item->ID).' - odmiana czasownika">';
                echo 'to '.get_field('en1');
                echo '</a></td><td>';
                echo do_shortcode(get_field('player2')); echo get_field('en2');
                echo '</td><td>';
                echo do_shortcode(get_field('player3')); echo get_field('en3');
                echo '</td><td>';
                echo '<span class="float-right">';
                echo get_field('poziom');
                echo '</span>';
                echo get_field('pl');
                echo '</td></tr>';
                if (get_field('przyklad_en')) {
                echo '<tr style="display:none;"><td></td></tr><tr class="en-vocab-example"><td colspan="2">';
                echo do_shortcode(get_field('przyklad_player')); echo get_field('przyklad_en');
                echo '</td><td colspan="2">';
                echo get_field('przyklad_pl');
                echo '</td></tr>';
                }
                ?>
            <?php
        endwhile;
        echo '</tbody></table>';
        wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $arr_posts ));
    endif;
```

Comment: by "dynamically" you mean without reloading/refreshing the page ?

Comment: Yes. Sorry if it's not the professional description, I'm unfamiliar with this process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since in the comments you explained by dynamically you mean without reloading/refreshing the page.
the answer to the first question is: yes, you will use AJAX calls.

first, create the search input
`<input name='input_name' placeholder="<?php echo __('search','textdomain'); ?>">`
second, the Javascript registered and enqueued script in `functions.php`

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("[name=input_name]").keyup(function () {
      $.post(
        ajaxurl,
        /*
            if ajaxurl is not defined you need to use wp_localize_script()
            or depending on how your wordpress is hosted use simply admin-ajax.php
        */
        {
          action: "random-name",
          search_data: $(this).val(),
        },
        function (response) {
          // use "response" to draw the new table rows
        }
      );
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

finally in your `functions.php`

```
function my_ajax_handler(){
    $_POST['search_data']; // here the searched word, push it to $args then run the loop Query again
    wp_die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_random-name','my_ajax_handler');
```

keep in mind there are existing plugins for tables. but doing an AJAX call yourself shouldn't be that hard.
the code above does the task.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. It solves my case.